# Why `diag_mdlog` not able to write on `/sdcard` if it is fired from an Android App that has write permissions?

Tags: root-access, linux, permissions, file-permissions, aosp

I am getting a weird behavior with `diag_mdlog` executable. I am executing it from my Android app as

> su -c /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg

The issue is:

- if the android app has granted `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` then it exits with permissions denied error as the following logs:

```
01-20 17:56:35.403 19087 19087 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: command = o
01-20 17:56:35.403 19087 19087 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: command = f
01-20 17:56:35.403 19087 19087 E Diag_Lib: diag: No Session is active for the given mask
01-20 17:56:35.403 19087 19087 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: Error creating: /sdcard/abc, errno: 13
01-20 17:56:35.403 19087 19087 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: Attempting to use default directory
01-20 17:56:35.403 19087 19087 E Diag_Lib: diag:In main failed to create xml file
01-20 17:56:35.403 19087 19087 E Diag_Lib:
01-20 17:56:35.403 19087 19087 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: Continuing with default directory path /sdcard/diag_logs/20200120_175635
01-20 17:56:35.403 19087 19087 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: Unable to create directory, errno: 13 Exiting....
```

- OTOH, if the app has not granted both the permissions then it works fine as the following logs:

```
01-20 17:57:38.258 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: command = o
01-20 17:57:38.258 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: command = f
01-20 17:57:38.258 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: diag: No Session is active for the given mask
01-20 17:57:38.259 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: Warning output directory already exists: /sdcard/abc
01-20 17:57:38.259 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: Proceeding...
01-20 17:57:38.270 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib:
01-20 17:57:38.270 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: Diag_LSM_Init succeeded.
01-20 17:57:38.270 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib:
01-20 17:57:38.270 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib:  REMOTE PROCESSOR MASK 0
01-20 17:57:38.270 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: diag:kernel supported: NUM_PERIPHERALS = 6, DIAG_CON_ALL: 127
01-20 17:57:38.271 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib:  logging switched
01-20 17:57:38.271 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: Output dirs /sdcard/abc --- /sdcard/abc
01-20 17:57:38.271 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib:
01-20 17:57:38.271 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: diag_mdlog: Reading mask for MSM, proc_type: 0
01-20 17:57:38.271 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: Reading the mask file: /sdcard/Test.cfg
01-20 17:57:38.271 19364 19364 E Diag_Lib: diag: Determining contents of directory /sdcard/abc for circular logging ...
01-20 17:57:42.446 19364 19368 E Diag_Lib:  creating new file /sdcard/abc/diag_log_20200120_1757421579523262440.qmdl
```

Now, if I will deny write permissions from Android settings then I will get further error logs as the following:

```
01-20 18:00:18.799 19364 19368 E Diag_Lib: diag: In log_to_device, error writing to sd card, Permission denied, errno: 13
01-20 18:00:18.799 19364 19368 E Diag_Lib:  failed to write to file, device may be absent, errno: 13
01-20 18:00:18.799 19364 19368 E Diag_Lib:  File open error, please check
01-20 18:00:18.799 19364 19368 E Diag_Lib:  memory device -1, errno: 13
01-20 18:00:18.800 19364 19368 E Diag_Lib:  File open error, please check
01-20 18:00:18.800 19364 19368 E Diag_Lib:  memory device -1, errno: 13
```

**Update 1**
I have just tried to play with quotes around the command and it has following result:

```
DL is diag_mdlog logs
PL is java.lang.Process :: error stream logs

# Samsung S10 5G
    * Read/Write permissions GRANTED

        - su -c /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg
        DL: - diag_mdlog: Unable to create directory, errno: 13 Exiting....

        - su -c '/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg'
        PL: - /system/bin/sh: /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg: not found

        - su -c `/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg`
        DL: - diag_mdlog: Unable to create directory, errno: 13 Exiting....

        - su -c "/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg"
        PL: - /system/bin/sh: /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg: not found

    * Read/Write permissions Denied

        - su -c /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg
        * Run FINE.

        - su -c '/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg'
        PL: - /system/bin/sh: /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg: not found

        - su -c `/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg`
        * Run FINE.

        - su -c "/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg"
        PL: - /system/bin/sh: /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg: not found


# Mi K20 PRO
    * Read/Write permissions GRANTED

        - su -c /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg
        DL: - diag_mdlog: Unable to create directory, errno: 13 Exiting....

        - su -c '/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg'
        PL: - /system/bin/sh: /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg: inaccessible or not found

        - su -c `/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg`
        DL: - diag_mdlog: Unable to create directory, errno: 13 Exiting....

        - su -c "/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg"
        PL: - /system/bin/sh: /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg: inaccessible or not found

    * Read/Write permissions Denied

        - su -c /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg
        * Run FINE.

        - su -c '/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg'
        PL: - /system/bin/sh: /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg: inaccessible or not found

        - su -c `/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg`
        * Run FINE.

        - su -c "/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg"
        PL: - /system/bin/sh: /vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg: inaccessible or not found
```

**Update 2**
I was just wondering to run it in background process with

> su -c `/vendor/bin/diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/abc -f /sdcard/Test.cfg &`
>   but it is also not working.

Even creating the following shell script at `/system/script/` with giving 755 permissions and executing it doesn't help me.

`exec_diag_mdlog.sh`:

```
raphaelin:/system/scripts # cat exec_diag_mdlog.sh
#!/system/bin/sh

diag_mdlog -o /sdcard/oem_logs -f /sdcard/Test.cfg &

raphaelin:/system/scripts #
```

Any suggestion to let the command will not execute in the context of app?

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: Read about how Android makes use of mount namespaces to control storage permissions. And UIDs/GIDs `1015`, `9997`. Does the command work from Termux? Also quote the whole command like: `su -c '...'`.

Comment: It does work with adb shell and also from any app that doesn't have Write permissions granted.

Comment: No luck with a single quote. I have updated the question with more detail.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Is it possible to run a command to create a process that runs `diag_mdlog` executable beyond the context of an android application? (I know I can do this with init scripts but I want something that I can execute from my app directly)

Comment: @IrfanLatif Is it possible?: 1. Create a shell script that will start/stop `diag_mdlog`. 2. Create custom prop(something like in build.prop) 3. Create an init script to run the shell script based on the custom prop. 4. Now the app can enable/disable custom prop to start/stop `diag_mdlog`

Comment: Yes it's definitely possible. Executing directly from app should also work (if it works from a terminal emulator app; directly on terminal and in shell script). But it's more about app development how you need to execute it from within app. When executing `su` you run it with Magisk context, not app context. As I mentioned in my first comment, do take care of mount namespace separation regarding storage permission. Run with `strace` to get more specific reason of failure.